# htttp live streaming receiving frames or videos from php server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I was wondering if i could transmit a live video  using flash from my php server and send it to my iphone? I was thinking if flash doesn't work, i would transmit it frame by frame. I need help in finding source code that would allow me to receive a live video from my php server.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to get video converted to hls to transmit it to the iphone. You cannot stream from a flash server to iPhone. You can simply remux your content (without re-encoding) to hls as long as the input has periodic I pictures. To understand the nitty grities go through this: http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/

If you don't mind using a command line tool, use ffmpeg. It should be able to recieve your live stream and then create a hls output from it. Ensure the dump goes to a http server and you can access the content from the iPhone.